# How load textures in Balder?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, 3d

I use Balder engine to work with 3D objects. I have ***.ase** file which contain

```
*MAP_DIFFUSE {
        *MAP_NAME "carrier_body"
        *MAP_CLASS "Bitmap"
        *MAP_SUBNO 1
        *MAP_AMOUNT 1.0000
        *BITMAP "//carrier_body.tga"
                    ........
```

I've added my **ase** file and **carrier_body.tga** to resource of the project but when I load mesh from **ase**

```
var tank=ContentManager.Load<Mesh>("tanks_carrier.ase");
```

I've caught the exception:

> There is no loader for the specified file type 'tga'

How right way to loading textures for **ase** file in **Balder**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed the problem. Balder is not supported **tga** format for textures, I've used **png** texture and all worked nice.